# Chef Template Whitespace Formatting

Tags: templates, chef-infra, recipe

I have a hash of key:value pairs that is to be printed. All of the keys are Strings of varying length, and for
readability, I would like the output to be formatted in two columns.

```
<% @foo.each do |bar| %>
    <%= bar['key'] %>  <%= bar['value'] %>
<% end %>
```

Is it possible to accomplish this, either through a setting in my recipe or on the template itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the non-printing tags (i.e. `<% %>`) you can use `-` to trim whitespace. `<%-` will remove whitespace before the tag and `-%>` will remove whitespace after the tag. If you do `<%- @foo.each do |bar| -%>` and `<%- end -%>` it will remove the blank lines entirely. How you do the padding for the printing lines, look at the Ruby methods `ljust` and `rjust`.

Comment: Thanks. I can use rjust on each line, passing in the longest string found for bar['key'] to accomplish what I want to do.